# How to play raw char* buffer with Gstreamer?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have char* buffer that I read from video.mp4 file. This buffer has size 4096.
I tried to create GstBuffer from char* buffer

```
GstBuffer* Buffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped(data, size);
dataBuffer = gst_buffer_copy(tmpBuf);
```

Then I push this buffer to the **appsrc**

```
GstElement* source = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (consumer), "source");
gst_app_src_push_buffer (GST_APP_SRC (source), dataBuffer);
gst_object_unref (source);
```

Pipeline **consumer** was created in the next way:

```
gchar* videoConsumerString = g_strdup_printf ("appsrc max-buffers=5 drop=false name=source ! decodebin ! xvimagesink");
consumer = gst_parse_launch (videoConsumerString, NULL);
gst_element_set_state (consumer, GST_STATE_NULL);
g_free (videoConsumerString);
```

After the create of pipeline I set its state to the GST_STATE_NULL. 
When I starts playing I set its state to GST_STATE_PLAYING.

But in the out I got error:

```
ERROR from element mpegvparse0: No valid frames found before end of stream
```

I tried to change size of char* buffer, use different elements in the pipeline (e.g. ffmpegcolorspace, videconvert, some other) but did not resolve this issue.

If run with GST_DEBUG=3, i have a lot of warnings

```
0:00:00.064480642  4059      0x12c66d0 WARN    codecparsers_mpegvideo gstmpegvideoparser.c:887:gst_mpeg_video_packet_parse_picture_header: Unsupported picture type : 0
```

I use gstreamer 1.0.
Does anybody faced with such problem?

P.S. I don't have possibility to read data from file with Gstreamer. I only can read buffers from file with fread and then try to play them.
Maybe I have to set some specific fixed size of readed buffer?

Comment: Did you used [this](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/tests/examples/app/appsrc_ex.c) example? how was that eos created(I mean end of stream - who created that, are you doing this somehow)? My guess is that you push the buffer after EOS.. do you see any warnings regarding this (run with `GST_DEBUG=3 ./your_app`)

Comment: Why '''gst_element_set_state (consumer, GST_STATE_NULL);'''? WHen are you setting it to '''GST_STATE_PLAYING'''? We probably need a more complete code snippet. Also seeing ffmpegcolorspace tells me that you are using gstreamer-0.10 which has not been updated for years. Please consider switching to 1.X especially for new code.

Comment: @otopolsky
No, used https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-data-spoof.html example, but they a almost similar.
I push EOS to the buffer when all data a already pushed. I updated the body of question.

If run with GST_DEBUG=3, i get a lot of
codecparsers_mpegvideo gstmpegvideoparser.c:887:gst_mpeg_video_packet_parse_picture_header: Unsupported picture type : 0

Comment: @ensonic 
I set pipeline to the GST_STATE_PLAYING when when I finished initializing of other objects.

I use gstreamer 1.0. I don't know why I did not got an error when tried to use ffmpegcolorspace.

Comment: ok I guess you do some processing to the mp4 files (otherwise you would simply use filesrc) - check the altered buffers. I just noticed the size 4096 mentioned at the beginning of question - is it in Bytes? this is quite small for the video buffer.. also you should provide some caps for the appsrc.. are you doing this somewhere? if so please paste all relevenat code snippets..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem.
Unexpectedly for me it was in the creating of the GstBuffer.

Correct way to create such buffer from data(char*) with known size is

```
    GstBuffer * buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, size, NULL);
    gst_buffer_fill(m_dataBufferProducer, 0, data, size);
```

Thank you for your help!